# How do I get a permanent legal right to work in the United States?

Tags: visas, usa, work

I live and work in Russia, and sometimes I find myself wondering about the job opportunities out there in the world. For instance, [Fog Creek](http://www.fogcreek.com/) offers an internship program for young developers.

**I'd love to travel to the USA for a couple of months to go through internship at some cool company.**

On [Fog Creek internship page](http://www.fogcreek.com/Jobs/SummerIntern.html) (as I believe on any other), the requirements include:

> Permanent legal right to work in the United States (includes TN status).

However, I'm not (currently) eligible for it, as **I don't have the permission to work in the USA**. My visa type is **B1/B2**, which is for business and travel needs only.

My questions are:

- Can I obtain **the right to work in the USA** if I live in Russia?
- **What kind of paperwork** is involved, and is it only required on my side, or potential employer would have to do something as well?
- If I make an application, **how would the US determine if I'm a good candidate**? What would they be looking for?

Comment: I think this type of question is quite off-topic for the travel.SE.

Comment: It may well be. But [visa questions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa) constitute a large part of site's questions as it is now, and although the goals may be different, I suspect “going to US for work” counts as a form of “traveling”. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Well, I don't want to close this question by myself, let's see what community will say.

Comment: this is not tourist visa question , but work visa, i don´t think it have much with travelling but it is business question

Comment: all open questions about visas here are not about business

Comment: @SergeS: I don't see how this question is about *business*. I see your point that it isn't strictly a traveling question but going to another country for a couple of months on your own *is* traveling, not “business”. Don't forget that other people might want to *travel* inside the USA but are unable to do so because they know they won't be able to get a legal job, and traveling rarely pays for itself, right? This question would answer their concerns, too.

Comment: I think this is more related to the [Immigration.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10331/immigration)

Comment: Thanks for the question Dan. This is a perfect fit for Immigration.SE but in it current form, it's off-topic on Travel.SE so I will have to close this question. Hope you understand! :)

Comment: The one and only way to do **literally what you say** is marry an American person.  This is trivial to do and zillions of people do it all the time. That's the one and only way to get the "right to live in the US forever and do what you want."  One step down from that is, very simply, ***a company*** sponsors you to work there.  Forget that unless you're a senior professional ($125,000+) in some field.  There is, very simply, **no mechanism whatsoever for "you"** to get a visa.  In the old days a simple trick was you could form a company and that company sponsored you! They stopped that.

Comment: (Exceptionally, the US, like all countries, has a Magic Pass for anyone who is rich (ie, net worth over say $3million).  It's usually called an "investor visa" or something to make poor people feel better that the world is so unfair. But if you have millions in the bank it's inconceivable you'd go "live in New Jersey" so this is irrelevant, you'd be emailing from Gstaad or the like.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only plausible way of getting a work permit in the US is by getting a H1B visa. Normally for that you need a job in the US which is also ready to sponsor your H1B visa. However there are a lot of agents who help you get to the US by showing 'fake' jobs and sponsoring your H1b visa for a hefty sum.

If you have lots and lots of money (in the range of $500,000 - $1,000,000) you could apply for an investor's visa.

EDIT:
There are also other ways of getting into US i.e. get Canadian residency and then go to US (much easier)

Comment: Thanks! I found some price info [here](http://www.h1base.com/visa/work/H1B%20Visa%20Fees/ref/1186/), is it right that an H1B will cost ~$3K to the employer?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa#Hidden_costs_and_risks_for_employers - That will give you a picture

Comment: please don't advise people to break the law by circumventing visa requirements. Thank you

Comment: @jwenting It wasn't advice, it was just info.

Comment: hi freethinker ... *"there are a lot of agents who help you get to the US by showing 'fake' jobs and sponsoring your H1b visa for a hefty sum"*  This is just not true anymore.  Everyone did this in, say, the 90s. But, simply, it's been stopped.  Are you sure you're up to date on this, free?  And yes, @dan, free is spot on regarding Canada. (I'm surprised you're not aware of that as a Russian!  :)   It's so common.)

Comment: For an internship position, a J1 visa is also allowed (up to 1 year)

Comment: You answered about a work permit, but the question included the word "permanent."